# imagecolorallocate returns 0 for background color

Tags: php, gd

I'm trying to create a bar-code and I'm having issue with it.

This is my code

```
$number = $this->uri->segment(3);
$width = 200;
$height = 80;

$img = imagecreate($width, $height); 
$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255); // return 0
$black = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0); // return 1  
imagettftext($img, 36, 0, 10, 50, $black, $barcode_font, $number); 
imagettftext($img, 14, 0, 40, 70, $black, $plain_font, $number);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

But it isn't creating a bar-code, it said : The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors. Please give me idea to solve this issue, still I cannot find any solutions for this

Comment: Please indicate what the issue is that you're having, specifically.

Comment: omg, I forgot that and didn't notice. Thank you @CamW

Comment: Your code works for me, once I set the barcode font to one I have installed and set `$number` to `12345`.  Remove the `header(...)` line so that you can see the actual error and edit it into your question.